# Test the uniform convergency of a series of function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Consider the series of function $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x}{1+n^2x}.$$

Show that this series of function is NOT uniformly convergent in $[0,1]$.

I know only two methods to show a series of function to NOT uniformly convergent :

(i) Using definition of uniform convergent.

(ii) Showing that term by term integration is not possible.

i.e. showing that$$\int_0^1\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n(x)\,dx\not =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_0^1f_n(x)\,dx.$$

But in each case we need to find out the finite sum $\sum_{k=1}^{n}f_k(x)$.

I am not able to find out this finite sum.

Please help on it....

Does there any other process or theorem to find that the series is not uniformly convergent ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may observe that, with $\displaystyle f_n(x)=\frac{x}{1+n^2x}$, $x \in [0,1]$, we have
$$
(f_n(x))'=\frac{1}{(1+n^2x)^2}>0
$$ thus $\displaystyle f_n(x)$ is increasing with $x$:
$$
0<\sup_{[0,1]}f_n(x)=f_n(1)=\frac{1}{1+n^2} \leq \frac{1}{n^2},
$$since $\displaystyle \sum\frac{1}{n^2}$ is convergent, hence
**your initial series is uniformly convergent in $[0,1]$.**

Comment: But in book from where I collect this problem, tells that the given series is uniformly convergent in $[\alpha,1]$ for $\alpha >0$ but **NOT** uniform convergent in $[0,1]$

Comment: Proof $>$ book :-).

Comment: It is an exercise problem...

Comment: Weierstrass M-Test.

Comment: If the series is uniformly convergent then what is the limit function ?

Comment: Yes, the way it is stated, the series does indeed converge uniformly on [0,1]. Are you sure that this is the correct formula for the function?

Comment: @Olivier Oloa): Well..now there are no doubt that the series is uniformly convergent in $[0,1]$. But I have another question : Is the series uniformly convergent on R ? In R I notice that the the Weierstress-M test is not applicable , as we can't find any upper bound in R. Then what happence ? I think it is NOT uniform convergent..But I can'not prove this

Answer (score 0):

Similar to (ii), the strategy is to find a theorem that must be true if the sum is to converge uniformly, and show that it is not true.

One theorem that is applicable in this case is that the limit function must be continuous (See Remark in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test).

But when x=0 the sum is zero and for any nonzero x it is bounded away from zero.

Comment: How you find the limit function?

Comment: I know that to converge uniformly limit function must be continuous..But I am unable to find the limit function..If you demonstrate what is the limit function and how you find it then then there is no need of anything

Comment: You don't need to know exactly what it is.  Just prove there is a jump discontinuity at zero.  Then by the Weierstrass M test the series cannot converge uniformly.

Comment: The condition of Weierstress M test is sufficient...not necessary..Let $\sum f_n(x)\le \sum M_n$..If $\sum M_n$ is convergent the the series $\sum f_n(x)$ is uniformly convergent..But it is not that $\sum M_n$ is not converge implies  the series is not uniformly convergent..

Comment: I really don't understand what do you mean actually..

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, just doesn't fit in the comments.

Olivier's answer shows that the function is continuous on $[0,1]$.

Here is an Octave plot of the sum of the first 100 terms:

[image]

In fact, the function is smooth on any compact subset of $(0,1]$.

Comment: ): Well..now there are no doubt that the series is uniformly convergent in $[0,1]$. But I have another question : Is the series uniformly convergent on $\mathbb R$ ? In $\mathbb R$ I notice that the the Weierstress-M test is not applicable , as we can't find any upper bound in $\mathbb R$. Then what happence ? I think it is NOT uniform convergent..But I can'not prove this